# How to place thick vertical line in table

Tags: tables, line

I have a table like this at the moment:

[image]

Made up of the following LaTeX:

```
\begin{table} [htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{p{2.50cm}|p{0.25cm}|p{0.25cm}|p{0.25cm}|p{0.25cm}}
            % \multirow{1}{*} {\textbf{Authors}} & & & & & & & & \textbf{Context and use of RSS} \\        &
            & \rotatebox{90}{Student 3} &
            \rotatebox{90}{Student 4} &
            \rotatebox{90}{Student 6} &
            \rotatebox{90}{Student 9} \\
            \thickhline
            Student 3 & & & & \\
            \hline
            Student 4 & \checkmark & & \\
            \hline
            Student 6 & \checkmark & \checkmark & \\
            \hline
            Student 9 & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \\
            \thickhline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Averaging of correlations for RSS feed 140.}
        \label{tab:CorrelationAveraging}
    \end{table}
```

But would like to have the first vertical line as thick as either the first horizontal line or last horizontal line.

Can anyone advise how this can be done with the packages specified in the MWE below?

Instruction `\thickhline` is:

```
\newcommand{\thickhline}{%
    \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 1.5pt
    \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}
```

A full MWE is listed below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
% \usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\marginsize{2.54cm}{2.54cm}{2.54cm}{2.54cm}

% Tables.
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.25ex}
\setlength\lightrulewidth{0.25ex}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont pair}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thickhline}{%
   \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 1.50pt
   \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}
\newcolumntype{"}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\vrule width 1pt\hskip\tabcolsep}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author{Author}

\maketitle

    \begin{table} [htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{1.65cm}|p{0.25cm}|p{0.25cm}|p{0.25cm}|p{0.25cm}}
        % \multirow{1}{*} {\textbf{Authors}} & & & & & & & & \textbf{Context and use of RSS} \\        &
        & \rotatebox{90}{Student 3} &
        \rotatebox{90}{Student 4} &
        \rotatebox{90}{Student 6} &
        \rotatebox{90}{Student 9} \\
        \thickhline
        Student 3 & & & & \\
        \hline
        Student 4 & \checkmark & & \\
        \hline
        Student 6 & \checkmark & \checkmark & \\
        \hline
        Student 9 & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \\
        \thickhline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Example of averaging of correlations for a sentiment for RSS feed 140.}
    \label{tab:CorrelationAveraging}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should create a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that starts at `\documentclass` and ends at `\end{document}` including all the necessary packages to recreate your problem but not more.

Comment: MWE has been added.

Comment: Note that your example is far from minimal. You include many unrelated packages and add much unrelated code (`\maketitle`, `\marginsize`...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel: it all exists with  the `\hlineB`, `clineB` commands and the `V` column separator, defined in the `boldline` package, from  the `shipunov` bundle. They all accept a number as an argument, which is a factor in front of `\arrayrulewidth`. Rules with 1.5pt thickness are approximately `4\arrayrulewidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array, boldline, rotating}

\newcommand{\thickhline}{\hlineB{4}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{2.50cm}V{4}*{4}{p{0.25cm}|}}
        % \multirow{1}{*} {\textbf{Authors}} & & & & & & & & \textbf{Context and use of RSS} \\ &
        & \rotatebox{90}{Student 3} &
        \rotatebox{90}{Student 4} &
        \rotatebox{90}{Student 6} &
        \rotatebox{90}{Student 9} \\
        \thickhline
        Student 3 & & & & \\
        \hline
        Student 4 & \checkmark & & & \\
        \hline
        Student 6 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & \\
        \hline
        Student 9 & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \\
        \thickhline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Averaging of correlations for RSS feed 140.}
    \label{tab:CorrelationAveraging}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since you have not provided the [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/154390), I have given you the freedom to do it with a different package ([tabu](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabu)) and this is the result:

[image]

Is it what you are looking for?

Here is the MWE code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu} % Nice tables package.
\usepackage{graphicx} % to rotate text
\usepackage{stix} %for checkmark
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Allows the definition of hex colors
\usepackage{colortbl} % %just in case
\definecolor{tabu}{HTML}{002fa7} % define and name "tabu" Klein blue HTML
\begin{document}
\begin{table} [htbp]
    \tabulinesep = 2mm
    \taburulecolor{tabu}
    \tabulinestyle{3pt tabu!70}
    \centering
    \begin{tabu} to 4.5cm {X[9]|X|[.5pt]X|[.5pt]X|[.5pt]X|}  

        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& \rotatebox{90}{Student 3} &
        \rotatebox{90}{Student 4} &
        \rotatebox{90}{Student 6} &
        \rotatebox{90}{Student 9} \\ \tabucline-
        Student 3 & & & & \\ \tabucline[.5pt] -
        Student 4 & \checkmark & & & \\ \tabucline[.5pt] -
        Student 6 & \checkmark & \checkmark & &\\ \tabucline[.5pt] -
        Student 9 & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \\ \tabucline-
    \end{tabu}
    \caption{Averaging of correlations for RSS feed 140.}
    \label{tab:CorrelationAveraging}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You dont need to make an aditional macros.

Comment: The MWE has been added to the end of original question. Can the vertical line be made thick using the packages apecified in the MWE?

Comment: Ok, I post this before that update, but nothing is missing that prevents it from compiling, it is not an MWE because it does not copy and paste and you give it to run; but if you add the necessary packages I do not think that it presents problems, except compatibilities with other packages that you have ...

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you can use all the king of rules provided by TikZ. Here an example with the style `very thick` of TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz,rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [htbp]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{2.50cm}|[tikz=very thick]*{4}{p{0.25cm}|}}
    & \rotatebox{90}{Student 3} &
    \rotatebox{90}{Student 4} &
    \rotatebox{90}{Student 6} &
    \rotatebox{90}{Student 9} \\
    \Hline[tikz=very thick]
    Student 3 & & & & \\
    \Hline
    Student 4 & \checkmark & & & \\
    \Hline
    Student 6 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & \\
    \Hline
    Student 9 & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \\
    \Hline[tikz=very thick]
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Averaging of correlations for RSS feed 140.}
\label{tab:CorrelationAveraging}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]